cross compiling Python-3.12 on windows
I am trying to cross compile Python-3.12 on windows, the base python required is Python-3.12 but cygwin only supports Python-3.9. How to overcome this dependency, if anyone has achieved cross compilation of Python-3.12 can you please share the steps.

Cross compile from Windows to what OS? Or from what OS to Windows? What does Cygwin have to do with it?

cross compiling from windows to linux. on windows I am using cygwin to cross compile. when using cygwin which has python 3.9 as base the build fails as python 3.9 is unable to interpret the match statement introduced in higher versions of python. Hence it has to be Python 3.12 on cygwin for cross compiling 3.12.

Cygwin normally produces windows apps, how do you cross-compile to linux with it? Why do you cross-compile Python in the first place, most distros have it in the package manager. And if you really want to build it yourself, why not use WSL?
